# Ruby 2.0.0, not 2.1.0 recommendation on Rails site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.1

At time of writing, on the [Ruby on Rails download page](http://rubyonrails.org/download), they recommend using Ruby 2.0.0 with Rails.

[Ruby 2.1.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/12/25/ruby-2-1-0-is-released/) was released at the end of December 2013.

Is that recommendation out of date? Do you have any tales of woe or joy about running Rails 4.0 on Ruby 2.1.0?

Comment: http://www.devalot.com/articles/2012/03/ror-compatibility

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current Ruby 2.1 version has some [segfault issues](https://meta.discourse.org/t/upgrade-to-ruby-2-1-0/11599) with Rails 4.0. Several fixes has already been [merged](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9470#change-44875) into master thanks to the work of [Amman](https://twitter.com/tmm1) who upgraded GitHub a few weeks ago.

I would suggest to hold off the switch of Ruby 2.1 for now, until Rails 4.1 and the first bugfix version of Ruby 2.1 are both released.

Comment: Can you use rails 4.1 with ruby 2.0.0?